# Error al cargar un archivo de texto a mysql, usando array con php.

Tags: mysqli, php7

Intento hacer la carga de un txt, con formato de codificación `utf8` y con separadores entre lineas `Þ` y entre campos `¶`.
Lo subo con un `form html` e `input type = file`. Tengo los archivos ordenados a manera de mvc. Y la versión de `php = 7.2.2` instalada.

Resulta que al hacer clic en el botón e intentar cargar el archivo a tabla, me esta arrojando el siguiente error : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'`  Es en el archivo modelo línea donde esta la función que recibe array como paramatros: `public function inserta_ventas`

?A que se debe el error y/o cuál puede ser una manera más eficiente de hacer la carga, cabe mencionar que son archivos pesados con miles de lineas?

Formulario

```html
   
       <form method="POST" action="../controles/load_ventas.php">
                <br>  
                <label for="a_venta">Carga de datos:</label>
                <input type="file" name="ventas" id="ventas"> 
                <br>             
           <div class='col-xs-6'>
           <h3 class='text-right'>   
           <input type="submit" name="registrar" id="registrar" class="btn btn-success" value="Carga">
           </h3>
           </div>  
        </form>
```

Controlador

```html
<?php

require "../config/Conexion.php";
require_once "../modelos/Ventas.php";

$ventas = new Ventas(); //objeto del modelo Ventas 

$archivo = isset($_POST["ventas"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["ventas"]):"";  //recibiendo archivo del form
 
$contenido = file_get_contents($archivo); //obteniendo contenido, formateado A UTF 8

     $filas = explode("Þ", $contenido); //delimitador entre lineas del fichero

     foreach ($filas as $linea) {

          $campos = explode("¶", $linea);  //dividiendo el string

          if(!empty($campos[0])) {

           $insert_vtas = $ventas->inserta_ventas($campos[0],$campos[1],$campos[2],$campos[3],$campos[4],
                          $campos[5],$campos[6],$campos[7],$campos[8],$campos[9],$campos[10],$campos[11],
                          $campos[12],$campos[13],$campos[14],$campos[15],$campos[16],$campos[17],
                          $campos[18],$campos[19],$campos[20],$campos[21],$campos[22],$campos[23],$campos[24],
                          $campos[25],$campos[26],$campos[27],$campos[28],$campos[29],$campos[30],$campos[31],
                          $campos[32],$campos[33],$campos[34],$campos[35],$campos[36],$campos[37],$campos[38],
                          $campos[39],$campos[40],$campos[41],$campos[42],$campos[43]);
           }
     }

?>
```

Modelo

```html
<?php
//Incluyendo la conexión a la BD
require "../config/Conexion.php";

Class Ventas
{
 //Implementando el constructor
 public function __construct()
 {

 }

 public function inserta_ventas($campos[0],$campos[1],$campos[2],$campos[3],$campos[4],
                      $campos[5],$campos[6],$campos[7],$campos[8],$campos[9],$campos[10],
                      $campos[11],$campos[12],$campos[13],$campos[14],$campos[15],$campos[16],$campos[17],
                      $campos[18],$campos[19],$campos[20],$campos[21],$campos[22],$campos[23],$campos[24],
                      $campos[25],$campos[26],$campos[27],$campos[28],$campos[29],$campos[30],$campos[31],
                      $campos[32],$campos[33],$campos[34],$campos[35],$campos[36],$campos[37],$campos[38],
                      $campos[39],$campos[40],$campos[41],$campos[42],$campos[43])
 {
  $sql="INSERT INTO ventas306(clave_area,area_vta,fecha_contable,sesion,fecha_apertura,hora_apertura,av_p,
        transaccion,operacion,id_vta,tipo,origen,destino,fecha_salida,hra_salida,f_boleto,asiento,pasajero,
        campo19,f_pago,ef,tb,pu,tr,do,gp,cv,importe,formato_salto,fecha_venta,hra_venta,corrida,empresa_corrida,
        t_boleto,referencia,autorizacion,voucher,t_servicio,fecha_cierre,razon_social,rfc,documento,empresa,fin) 

              VALUES ('$campos[0]','$campos[1]','$campos[2]','$campos[3]','$campos[4]',
                    '$campos[5]','$campos[6]','$campos[7]','$campos[8]','$campos[9]',
                    '$campos[10]','$campos[11]','$campos[12]','$campos[13]','$campos[14]',
                    '$campos[15]','$campos[16]','$campos[17]','$campos[18]','$campos[19]','$campos[20]',
                    '$campos[21]','$campos[22]','$campos[23]','$campos[24]','$campos[25]','$campos[26]',
                    '$campos[27]','$campos[28]','$campos[29]','$campos[30]','$campos[31]','$campos[32]',
                    '$campos[33]','$campos[34]','$campos[35]','$campos[36]','$campos[37]','$campos[38]',
                    '$campos[39]','$campos[40]','$campos[41]','$campos[42]','$campos[43]')";

  return ejecutarConsulta($sql); 
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: en la declaración de tu función, no es necesario colocar `campos[i]`, puedes hacerlo como `public function inserta_ventas($campo1, $campo2, ...){` intenta cambiando eso, o simplemente recibe `$campos`como un arreglo, y ya puedes utilizar `$campos[1], $campos[2]` en dado caso tu función quedaría `public function inserta_ventas($campos){....`, y al llamar a la función desde la lectura del archivo, puedes pasar directamente el resultado del `explode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes realizar el siguiente cambio en tu módelo, que te puede hacer más viable

```
public function inserta_ventas($campos){
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO ventas306(clave_area,area_vta,fecha_contable,sesion,fecha_apertura,hora_apertura,av_p,
          transaccion,operacion,id_vta,tipo,origen,destino,fecha_salida,hra_salida,f_boleto,asiento,pasajero,
          campo19,f_pago,ef,tb,pu,tr,do,gp,cv,importe,formato_salto,fecha_venta,hra_venta,corrida,empresa_corrida,
          t_boleto,referencia,autorizacion,voucher,t_servicio,fecha_cierre,razon_social,rfc,documento,empresa,fin) 

          VALUES ('$campos[0]','$campos[1]','$campos[2]','$campos[3]','$campos[4]',
                  '$campos[5]','$campos[6]','$campos[7]','$campos[8]','$campos[9]',
                  '$campos[10]','$campos[11]','$campos[12]','$campos[13]','$campos[14]',
                  '$campos[15]','$campos[16]','$campos[17]','$campos[18]','$campos[19]','$campos[20]',
                  '$campos[21]','$campos[22]','$campos[23]','$campos[24]','$campos[25]','$campos[26]',
                  '$campos[27]','$campos[28]','$campos[29]','$campos[30]','$campos[31]','$campos[32]',
                  '$campos[33]','$campos[34]','$campos[35]','$campos[36]','$campos[37]','$campos[38]',
                  '$campos[39]','$campos[40]','$campos[41]','$campos[42]','$campos[43]')";

    return ejecutarConsulta($sql); 
}
```

y al hacer tu llamado desde tu controlador

```
$campos = explode("¶", $linea);
....
$insert_vtas = $ventas->inserta_ventas($campos);
```

Comment: listo, lo he cambiado, pero ahora tengo otro error en el controlador, al cargar el archivo me dice:    "Warning: file_get_contents(Ene2016.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in"
Creo que es el uso de la función. ?Cuál debe ser la correcta?.

Comment: no esta alcanzando el fichero, en que carpeta esta tu fichero, para que logre ancanzarlo el script php

Comment: esta localmente en directorio: C:\ventas

Comment: pero lo estas subiendo al servidor, debes de leerlo, desde el directorio que te indique la variable `$_FILES['ventas']['tmp_name']`, puedes ver el contenido de `$_FILES`con `print_r($_FILES);

Comment: es, cierto, de que manera?

Comment: `$archivo = $_FILES['ventas']['tmp_name'];`, por eso te digo que veas como va definido en la variable `$_FILES`con la llamada `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: intentaré hacer la carga, y si no lo logro publico otra pregunta. gracias